# want to get my Droid back to stock, but don't want to reinstall apps

Tags: motorola-droid, stock-android, unrooting, unbricking

I foolishly rooted my Motorola Droid and fumbled around until I got Cyanogenmod 6.1.0-RC3-Droid installed on the thing. 
There's really no reason I should have done this, however. It didn't exactly solve my problems. Now, I have a few additional problems and would just like to get back to stock.

My first question is this:
What is the easiest way to just get this phone back to stock? Some posts talk about booting into recovery and just choosing factory reset - other posts say that isn't enough, etc.

Second question:
Can I use AppBrain to make the installation of all of my apps easier once I have the phone back to stock? I have 75 apps. I am hoping that I can just install AppBrain as the first app, then have it do the installs.

Has anyone done this?
Thanks.

UPDATE: I bricked my phone. I'm stuck in a loop of "Droid" and the animated eye icon.

Comment: Ideally, you would have made a NANDROID backup immediately after rooting your phone.  Then you could restore to the backup and perform the unroot method of whatever root method you used.

Comment: which steps did u take to brick your phone?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who has helped. I really had no business trying to do what I did. I have 3 kids and no time, so my impatience led to some bad choices.

Comment: I tried to use ROM Manager to download stock. Then I booted into recovery and tried to apply stock rom. It appeared to work but I got a "needs to update" message. It did something, rebooted, required another update, then got into a continuous loop of splash screens. Now I can't even boot into recovery. It just gives me an ugly ! with a triangle around it.

Comment: That's the stock recovery.  If you download a signed ROM (like a Master OTA), rename it to update.zip, and put it on the root folder of your SD card, you'll be able to flash it from recovery.  See the last link in my answer below for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your phone is almost certainly not permanently bricked.  Chances are you can boot into recovery to flash a new ROM.  Worst case, you'll have to flash the phone back to stock with RSD Lite.

That said, there's really no way to unroot the phone or flash a stock ROM without having to re-install your apps.  You can try flashing a stock ROM without wiping data & cache (or doing a factory reset), but it's probably not going to work very well.

The major apps for restoring 3rd party apps & their data, like Titanium Backup, require root.  You can use other avenues to re-install apps (like AppBrain), but you'll have to reconfigure them by hand if you're not rooted.  Since you say you're having problems, this might be the safest course of action for a large # of your apps anyway.  It's just a bear to lose complex configurations or progress in games.

Since your're already in trouble, the course of action I'd recommend is using RSD Lite to flash the latest SBF availble -- FRG22D in your case.  It's available for download from [Peter Alfonso's Site](http://www.peteralfonso.com/p/downloads.html).  Your phone will update to FRG83 via OTA.  Flashing the SBF will wipe all your phone's data.  You may even need to reactivate your phone with Verizon, but that's not difficult to do (just dial *228 and press 1).  This will not wipe your SD card, so things like backups you have or pictures/videos/downloads on the SD card will be safe.  Despite the dire warnings or bricking one's phone, as long as you don't do something foolish like unplug the phone (or pull battery) in the middle of flashing (or have bad luck with a power outage), you should be OK.  [Using SBF to root and unroot @ DroidForums](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/rescue-squad-guides/39254-sbf-root-unroot.html)

If you can still boot into recovery, you can flash the stock ROMs from there and accomplish nearly the same thing -- though I'm not sure it will do things like update baseband. [Unroot w/o SBF @ DroidForums](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/rescue-squad-guides/80664-unroot-back-stock-2-2-without-sbf-rsd-lite-droid-1-only.html)

The DroidForums guides are very thorough, and their Rescue Squad group is very helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I am back to stock (FRG83D). Now I need to see if AppBrain can help me do all of the installs to get my apps back.

Answer (score 2):

Before you un-root I'd recommend upgrading to the Stable release of CM 6.1 which may fix your problems.  If you do unroot you can use Appbrain to reload all your apps but you'll still have to re-enter in all your settings and what not.  If you stay rooted and use Titanium Backup you can reload all your apps from your SD card with all their settings intact.

As far as how to unroot I believe that is going to depend on how you rooted in the first place.  I am admittedly not an expert on this but I'm sure some others will chime in with some more details.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just do a factory reset.  Factory reset removes data and apps, it does not restore the entire OS/firmware on the phone.  Titanium Backup is probably the best to backup and restore your apps.  The best way to go back to stock would be:

1. Install ROM Manger from the Market (requires root)
2. Open it, click Flash ClockworkMod Recovery, choose your device if it asks
3. Click "Download ROM", and select the appropriate option (should be "Stock Droid" or something)
4. Click the notification when the download completes to install said ROM from ROM Manager.

If you had been using ROM Manager originally, you could have backed up before installing CyanogenMOD and you'd just have to do a simple restore from ROM Manager.