# Bricked Moto Defy

Tags: motorola-defy, unbricking

I have bricked my Motorola Defy.

I have tried flashing a new ROM using RSD Lite (following [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=853674) guide). It says 'complete' but my phone will not turn on. Sometimes it will just show the Moto boot logo but never fully boot up. I can only open the boot menu.

The ROMs I have tried flashing can be found [here](http://and-developers.com/sbf:defy) (All UK 2.1 at the top of the page).

Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**

I have looked at the answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3609/want-to-get-my-droid-back-to-stock-but-dont-want-to-reinstall-apps) but the recommended ROM was not compatible with my handset. Does anyone know which ROM to use for my defy ([here](http://www.peteralfonso.com/p/downloads.html))?

Comment: Did your phone come with or have a 2.2 ROM on it at any point? I feel like I read somewhere that trying to downgrade from 2.2->2.1 could cause a soft-brick, but flashing a 2.2 would work (might be thinking of a different phone, though...).

Comment: Hey, I think it came with 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which ROM you're looking for - but have you checked out the available ROMs on [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=855)?  Also suggest you check out this guide at [Modaco](http://www.modaco.com/topic/324375-guide-debranding-installing-differentrecovering-bricked-firmware-on-your-motorola-defy/) for how to flash/unbrick your phone.

Comment: Can you summarize the guide perhaps?  If the post gets remove or the site goes down this answer will become much less helpful.